# iOS zip file Unzipping code issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, unzip

I want to unzip a zip file downloaded from web but my issue is the zip file is not unzipping in if-else statement.

Is it wrong anything if it is then kindly guide me.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/zipfile.zip"];
NSError *error = nil;
// 2
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
if(!error)
{
    // 3
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *zipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"zipfile.zip"];

        [data writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];

       if(!error)
       {
            // TODO: Unzip
            ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
            // 1
           if ([za UnzipOpenFile: zipPath]) {
                // 2
                BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo: path overWrite: YES];
                if (NO == ret){} [za UnzipCloseFile];

                // 3
                NSString *imageFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.png"];
                NSString *textFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath options:0 error:nil];
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath
                                                                 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

                // 4           
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    self.imageView.image = img;
                    self.label.text = textString;
                });
}
else
{
            NSLog(@"Error saving file %@",error);
        }
   }
    else
  {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading zip file: %@", error);
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code debugging

1) NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

data is "nil"

by adding in plist below lines of code

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

you will get expected output

Comment: Accept and up vote the answer it will help to some one